# SAS Visual Analytics Cross Table Frequency Count

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

I am tryng to implement the cross table with frequency counts on SAS Visual Analytics.

Each raw of my source table is a result of bandwidth test of telco operators. There are several operators that have been tested, a number(many) tests has been done for each operator. Each test results with some throughput value.

The table has the Throughput column - connection speed - with discret values (e.g. 128, 512, 1024, etc)  which is the rounded value of actual connection speed and the name of the operator.

I need to build a table that will show the frequency of occurrence in percentage for each value of throughput per operator.

e.g.

```
      Orange  Vodafone T-Mobile  
128    1.1%     1.2%     
256    1.1%     1.4%
512    1.2%     1.5%
```

1024    1.3%     1.6%
    ...
    Total   100%     100%

I use standard cross table for my implementation and Throughput(Role - Category) as raws and operator names for columns and the predefined measurement  - Frequency Percent. However it seems to calculate the percentage of overall occurrence not per operator. When I apply a filter for an operator to limit the result for a single operator the calculations are correct.

I am new to SAS and will appreciate any suggestion or comment.

Thanks.

UPD: SAS Visual Analytics version is 9.4.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SAS Visual Analytics are you using?

For 6.3 you should be able to get to what you want by creating a "Percent of Subtotals" derived measure. This applies to crosstab only. You can choose the subtotal value for the rows or for the columns in the crosstab.

Comment: The version is 9.4. Thanks for the idea, I will have a look.

Comment: can you please give any hint on how to create Percent of Subtotals measure.

Comment: I do not currently have access to the software. If I remember correctly, you can create a derived measure by right clicking on a data item in the data panel on the left.

Comment: The only thing I found is Percent of Total, but in doesn't give correct result.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to write a custom aggregation function for Visual Report Designer in VA?